# Get -ChildItem length error

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I've to search `Search_String` Present in `All_Files/Folder/Sub_Folder` on particular drive so I've below command, but it is giving me error for some of the folder/Files where Length because `Must be Less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters`

Command :

```
Get-ChildItem D: -Recurse | Where-Object {(Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "Search_String" -Quiet) -eq $true} | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $_}
```

I've tried `Get-AlphaFSChildItems` instead of `Get-ChildItem` but it didn't work.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-AlphaFSChildItems-ff95f60f

Please help me to find the way-out.

Comment: The easiest way out is to use Windows 10, with the anniversary edition update, and then [enable long path support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/). I guess AlphaFS got the files, but Select-String could not read them, and that will be a problem for any approach you take - you will have to work around long paths every step of the way.

Comment: Thanks but I need to use this command on windows server 2012